# During an $.ajax call some data is lost

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with a multiple select box. When I select more than one option and send the form via an ajax cal to a php file, only the last option will be saved.
Why is that so?

This is the AJAX call:

```
var daten = $('#formulargesamt').serialize();
console.log(daten);

$.ajax({
  url: "/ajax/neukundenanlage/get_formular.php", 
  data: daten, 
  method: "POST",
});
```

In the `console.log` prompt all data is there (as a string). However in the PHP file it is an array with only the last selected option.

Does anyone have a ideas how I can fix this? Thanks

edit:

the html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/ajax/neukundenanlage/get_formular.php" method="post" 
    name="formular" id="formulargesamt">
```

(...)

```
    <div class="alert fade in" role="alert" id="resultmsg"  
    style="display:none;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
        label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> <span 
        id="resulttxt"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

the PHP code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

the prompt from console.log:

ed_kid=107&medienverzeichnis=konradin&ed_kbid=&ma_id=0&job_id=0&absendername=&fromaddress=&replyto=&feedbackadresse=&login=agotzens%40mbmedien.de&login=bcioba%40mbmedien.de

Comment: The important parts we need to see here is the string generated from `serialize()` and your PHP.

Comment: How is your html? The name attribute should be something like: name="date[]" instead of only name="date"

Comment: please provide your html code

Comment: HI folks, thanks for the replys. @Eva Why should I add an array-bracket to the name?

Comment: If ever you have input fields with the same name, adding an "array-bracket" will store it in an array. Without it, serialize will use the last input value.

Comment: When I added the "array-brackets" I got the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: @Peter, I just assumed that you have a checbox with multiple select optin because you wrote that you can only see the last selected option.

Comment: @Eva your hint worked, thanks